# Xcode Mac application (Swift) problems

Tags: xcode, swift, macos

I am working on a Mac application using Swift.

And I got a lot of problems there cause I thought it would be the same as I did it in the iOS application

I am really sorry about this long post :(

The first problem:

The error: "Method does not override any method from its superclass"

The code:

```
import Cocoa
```

class CreateAccountViewController: NSViewController {

```
@IBOutlet weak var emailTextField: NSTextField!
@IBOutlet weak var passwordTextField: NSSecureTextField!
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}
```

The next one:

Error:Value of type 'CreateAccountViewController' has no member 'dismissViewControllerAnimated'

Code:

```
self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
```

The last one:

The error: Use of unresolved identifier 'UIAlertController'

The code:

```
let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Error", message: "Enter Email and Password", preferredStyle: .Alert)
```

I am so sorry but this is my first time I wrote a Mac application.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`UIAlertController` is part of `UIKit` Library which is only available on iOS.

You'll need to use `NSAlert` to pop an alert in a window on Mac OS X. You also need to do an `import AppKit` at the top of your Swift file.

Comment: Yes but what do I have to write instead in the brackets?

Comment: You can initialize it empty like this : `let alert = NSAlert()`
You add the property you need after the initialization.
`alert.message = "Enter Email and Password"`

[NSAlert Class reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSAlert_Class/)

Comment: But now I got another error: Value of type 'NSAlert' has no member 'message'      In this code: `let alert = NSAlert()
            alert.message = "Enter Email and Password"`

Comment: @BenWelterveden AppKit is often different than UIKit, you can't just transpose your iOS skills like that to OS X, you have to learn the specificities first.

Comment: Yeah it's my bad. It should be `alert.messageText`, I linked the Class reference in my previous comment so you can check all the property you need.